# How to implement pie chart and hide watermark

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have used an area high chart where i need to hide the credits that are is shown `highcharts.com` how do i do it? I want to know is there any property through which I can hide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
credits: {
            enabled: false
        }
```

In your js this will hide the watermark.